# Is there a way to pass Python command line in JSON value

Tags: python, json

Is there a way to parse a Python command line into a json value and execute it back on python.
Json example:

```json
{
  "identifier": {
    "command":"print(\"Things to print\")",
  }
}
```

Example in python and how would be able to execute it?

```py
print = data['identifier']['command']
```

Comment: If the linked duplicate above doesn't answer your question, please [edit] the question to show what you tried and how it didn't work, to clarify / distinguish.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure much sense can be made of the question; as best I can figure it out, it's asking to do something that would be an *extremely bad idea*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, ...certainly, it's a bad idea; but if someone _wants_ to pursue that particular bad idea, the duplicate describes it. (The security impact is a whole 'nother question).